# getting an error when reading yahoo data using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with Python and Pandas.

**I have the following code below that is reading information for the stock Amazon:**

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pprint
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
import pandas as pd


def sample_reading_from_yahoo():
    # setting plotting, start  / end date and time
    style.use('ggplot')

    # setting up the date and time
    start = dt.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
    end = dt.date.today()

    # pull back the data
    yf.pdr_override()
    #data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AMZN", start, end="2017-09-12")

    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AMZN", start, end)

    data = data.rename(columns={'Open': 'open'})
    data = data.rename(columns={'High': 'high'})
    data = data.rename(columns={'Low': 'low'})
    data = data.rename(columns={'Close': 'close'})
    data = data.rename(columns={'Adj Close': 'adjusted'})
    data = data.rename(columns={'Volume': 'vol'})

    data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

    data = data[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']]
    return data


# MAIN
data = sample_reading_from_yahoo()
print(data)
```

**The output looks like the following:**

```
                   open         high          low        close       vol
Date                                                                    
2017-01-03   757.919983   758.760010   747.700012   753.669983   3521100
2017-01-04   758.390015   759.679993   754.200012   757.179993   2510500
2017-01-05   761.549988   782.400024   760.260010   780.450012   5830100
2017-01-06   782.359985   799.440002   778.479980   795.989990   5986200
2017-01-09   798.000000   801.770020   791.770020   796.919983   3440100
2017-01-10   796.599976   798.000000   789.539978   795.900024   2558400
```

**Whenever I make changes to MAIN area as follows,**

```
# MAIN

data = sample_reading_from_yahoo()
print(data)

data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

data.set_index(data.Date)
```

**I get the error below**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/dgmufasa/PycharmProjects/Opportunities/Opportunities.py",
>   line 96, in 
>       data = sample_reading_from_yahoo()   File "C:/Users/dgmufasa/PycharmProjects/Opportunities/Opportunities.py",
>   line 86, in sample_reading_from_yahoo
>       data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')   File
>   "C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 3614, in **getattr**
>       return object.**getattribute**(self, name) AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'

**How can I fix this?**

## MODIFICATIONS

@CK Chen - Thanks for the response.

**I made the following changes:**

```
def sample_reading_from_yahoo():
    [... snip ...]

    #print(data['vol'])

    data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

    data = data[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']]
    return data

# MAIN

data = sample_reading_from_yahoo()

#print(data.index)

data['datetime_index'] = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
data.set_index('datetime_index')

print('THIS THE DATA RESULT')
print(data)
```

**And got the result:**

```
THIS THE DATA RESULT
                   open         high          low        close       vol  \
Date                                                                       
2017-01-03   757.919983   758.760010   747.700012   753.669983   3521100   
2017-01-04   758.390015   759.679993   754.200012   757.179993   2510500   
2017-01-05   761.549988   782.400024   760.260010   780.450012   5830100    

           datetime_index  
Date                       
2017-01-03     2017-01-03  
2017-01-04     2017-01-04  
2017-01-05     2017-01-05
```

**It seems like the time format did not change. What did I do wrong?**

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The 'Date' is dataframe's index.name.
You can try:

```
data['datetime_index'] = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
data.set_index('datetime_index')
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I made the changes and the format for the date is still the same. Why is this the case?  See the "MODIFICATION" in the original post

Comment: you also said "The 'Date' is dataframe's index.name" - how can you tell this?

Comment: There's a blue "Date" on your index and that is the index name. For the format, pd.to_datetime is to parse date string to datetime object. Therefore, your need to use format string %Y-%m-%d which matches your date string.